# django allauth accounts before i18n or after?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am running into some problems with django allauth and i18n. I have accounts within my i18n urls and so it has a language code after the url...

This works great and it allows me to translate things in the accounts page like I want, the problem I have is that when I try to do social logins, particularly with google, the account redirect URI includes the language code...

```
/en/accounts/google/login/callkback
```

This causes a 404 because I do not have that path on the google redirect URI's. The only solutions I can see so far are either adding the accounts url outside of i18n and losing my ability to translate them, or specifically adding each language I offer within the google redirect URI's which may be tedious and may not be offered on other social providers...

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta add allauth to the `urlpatterns` using just `patterns`, then add to the other url's using `i18n_patterns`, so that django won't add language prefixes to the allauth urls.

Here's what mine looks like (I'm using python social auth, but same principle):

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
                        )

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('helpcenter.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
    url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

You can see that I added the python social auth url's separately, before adding the urls to the other apps